# Mnemonic for remembering how to spell "Guarantee"

Tags: orthography, mnemonic

It seems that I've been trying to remember how to spell `guarantee` for years, and I still find myself doing the right-click-fix, every. single. time.

Are there any tricks / mnemonics for this word?

Comment: what part do you have trouble with? "Two A's two 'E's"  or "G-U-A"?

Comment: Looks like you remembered this time, though.

Comment: Typically, it's remembering whether it's `U-A` or `A-U` and if that is pre or post `r`

Comment: @Robusto - I totally didn't; I copy/pasted from another window because SE titles don't have spell-check (and alas, I was wrong when I tried myself) :)

Comment: I could use this too, @MrDuk.  I have a mental block as to whether it's "G-u.." or "G-a..".  SMH

Comment: Yeah! Whence the "gawr" sound go?

Comment: How about "Gee, You Are pretty confident to offer this guarantee."  Gets the 'G-U' combo and puts it before the 'ARE'.  (You're on your own for the back half of the word, I'm afraid.)

Comment: What @Hellion said, or perhaps if you're more cynical-  Most guarantees aren't worth guano.

Comment: I usually find myself saying "goo-air-untee" in my head when I write it out.

Comment: On a golf course a Girl Under Arrest tries to escape police and RAN to the TEE. Get ir?

Comment: Old fashioned ways: write it out twenty times by hand. Write the word on a post-it note and stick it on something whose "guarantee" is running out. Spell the word out aloud ten times, stressing on the letters that you have trouble with. Write the word with your finger in the air. Write a question on EL&U asking for a tip. If this is your first question, you'll probably associate its spelling with the website. Just be sure that you've got *guarantee* spelled correctly in front of you, while you're doing this!

Comment: Guaranteed Under All Reasonable Actions. Note These Exceptions Exist.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know. Guarantee and guard are two words that seem to have a superfluous 'u', and in French they both omit the 'u' (garantie and garde). Normally the 'u' would be there to harden a 'g' before 'i' or 'e' in words of Latin origin, but it's useless here and therefore I can't think of an easy way of doing it!

Comment: It's not that helpful, but if you have a knack for remembering etymologies it might help to remember that these words are related to the words "warranty" and "ward"; and a "w" in Germanic words usually corresponds to a "gu" in Romance words (compare English "war" and French "guerre").